# How to display this data buffer in a QImage

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have an image I am trying to display in a QImage.

This is the snippet of code that populates the rows*cols image:

```
    rgbMapped[row][col * 3] = red;

    rgbMapped[row][col * 3 + 1] = green;

    rgbMapped[row][col * 3 + 2] = blue;
```

As you can see, my data buffer is "rows-high" and is "cols*3 wide"

rgbMapped is an unsigned char** array. So back in my QT code I have the following:

```
QImage *qi = new QImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), QImage::Format_RGB888);

for (int h = 0; h< getHeight(); h++){
    memcpy(qi->scanLine(h), rgbMapped[h], getWidth()*3);
}
QPixmap p(QPixmap::fromImage(*qi,Qt::ColorOnly));

if(scene.items().contains(item)){
    scene.removeItem(item);
}
item = new ImagePixmapItem(p);
scene.addItem(item);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(&scene);
ui->graphicsView->show();
```

ImagePixMapItem is a QGraphicsPixmapItem that I have created to allow me to intercept some mouse events, but I dindt do anyhting with any of the paint functions or anything.

When I run this code, my return comes back as an image that looks like my image, except there are three copies, one with a green tint, one looking yellow-ish and one with a noticeable purple tint.

It seems like maybe it would be the correct image if these three pieces of data were..overlayed on each other?

Comment: - I'd try to simplify the test case and save the image to a file instead or paint directly using QPainter. Just to make sure nothing goes wrong with QImage-QPixmap conversion or graphicsview. - My first guess would be that rows and columns get mixed up somehow.

Comment: By 3 copies, do you mean you have 3 of the same image squeezed horizontally or vertically into the same size of the image? Or the result is 3x the width or height as it suppose to?

Comment: It was 3x the width as it was supposed to be. I think that part could be because my getHeight() and getWidth() were returning dimensions of the array. Should that be dimensions of the image instead?

Comment: If getWidth() is an array dimension (=3 * image-width) the code above is not correct. In the "new QImage(...)" you should put getWidth()/3 and in the memcpy(..) you should put just getWidth() - not getWidth()*3. I think it will make your code more clear if getHeight(), getWidth() refer to the actual image semantics and not to the implementation details. In my answer bellow, I assumed that getWidth() was the actual image-width.

Comment: Yes, the width and height input for QImage is the pixel dimension, not your array size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an assumption, but from the (wrong) colors you mentioned, I suspect the problem could be with your allocation/initialization code regarding the `char **rgbMapped` variable.
Could you please post this code?

I will try to write bellow a possibly correct(?) initialization code 
just to give you a hint which may help (I haven't compile the code,
therefore I apologize for any syntax errors).
I use malloc() but you can also use the new() operator.

```
// allocate a single buffer for all image pixels
unsigned char *imgbuf = malloc(3 * getWidth() * getHeight());

// allocate row pointers
unsigned char **rgbMapped = malloc(getHeight() * sizeof (unsigned char *)); 

// Initialize row pointers
for (int h=0; h < getHeight(); h++)
{
  *rgbMapped[h] = &imgbuf[h * 3 * getWidth()];
}

// ... do your processing

// Free the image buffer & row pointers
free(imgbuf);
imgbuf = NULL;
free(rgbMapped);
rgbMapped = NULL;
```

The important part is the initialization of row pointers (did you forget the *3?).
Just my 2c.

Comment: I do like this method. You can get a contiguous block of memory that is accesible with bracket notation. +1

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion: In the code sample above, I assume that getHeight(), getWidth() refer to the actual image height and width - not the width of the required char arrays. Another approach is to allocate a single memory block on every row pointer, but it's slower and more prone to memory fragmentation situations in some systems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accounting for stride?
Each scanline must begin on a 4 byte boundary.
Also it may not be a packed pixel format, so each pixel is 4 bytes not 3

Comment: I did not know that the scanline had to be on a 4 byte boundary

Comment: It's not the problem here. He let QImage allocate the memory and use the scanline buffer from it. Any stride requirement will be handled by QImage code.